# How to chanhow to change from currentuser uid to id receipts

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a problem because I want to be in my storage and a photo from the id of my receipt from firestore has been added. I want this id from the firestore to be the currentUser id

this code:

```
  fun uploadReceiptPhoto(bytes: ByteArray) {
            storage.getReference("receipts")
                .child("${auth.currentUser!!.uid}.jpg")
                .putBytes(bytes)
                .addOnCompleteListener{
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, "COMPLETE UPLOAD PHOTO")
                }
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    getReceiptPhotoDownloadUrl(it.storage)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
                }
        }
        private fun getReceiptPhotoDownloadUrl(storage: StorageReference) {
            storage.downloadUrl
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    updateReceiptPhoto(it.toString())
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
                }
        }
        private fun updateReceiptPhoto(url: String) {
            cloud.collection("receipts")
                .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
                .update("image", url)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, "UPDATE USER PHOTO")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
                }
        }
```

EDIT CODE:

```
db.collection("receipts")
                .add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
                    db.collection("receipts")
                        .document(documentReference.id)
                        .update("id", documentReference.id)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {

                        }

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.w(SCAN_DEBUG, "Error adding document", e)
                }
```

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to replace currentUser with the id of the document from the receipts collection which is being created into the code that I have edited

Comment: And what's the behavior of this code? What exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamothe code only works instead of currentUser uid wants to change to the id of another document from a different collection

Comment: @AlexMamo the code only works instead of currentUser uid wants to change to the id of another document from a different collection

Comment: I'm sorry but I have hard times understanding what you need.

Comment: @AlexMamo what's the command to get the newly created document (code at the bottom) id and use it in place of the current user id?

Comment: So you want to change a particular document ID? Show us an example?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't want to change the identifier only in the code, I don't know how to access the document id